# Run location-based Shortcut to toggle airplane mode

Tags: automation, geolocation, shortcuts-app

I have a simple shortcut that turns on airplane mode when I arrive home. How can I trigger this to run automatically—without tapping for confirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 17 allows Location-based automations (except “Before I Commute”) to run without interaction.

Choose “Arrive," select your location, then choose “Run Immediately.”

Source: [Apple Support Article](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/7.0/ios/17.0), "Enable an automation to run without asking"

Comment: Figures - now that I have moved way from the home where I needed to do that.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I trigger this to run automatically—without tapping for confirmation?

### You can't.

Normally, you could make an automation (or convert your shortcut into an automation), disable "Ask Before Running" and click "Don’t Ask to confirm your choice" (see [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios) Apple Support article for more info and guidance).

> I have a simple shortcut that turns on airplane mode when I arrive home.

Unfortunately, the method mentioned above won't work for location-based automations (as well as other categories of automations). From [Enable or disable a personal automation in Shortcuts on iPhone or iPad - Enable an automation to run without asking](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios):

> The following automations cannot be run automatically:
>
> - **Arrive**
> - Leave
> - Before I Commute
> - Email
> - Message
> - Wi-Fi
> - Bluetooth

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

That was probably made like that for security purposes concerning possibly sensible informations.

Comment: I knew this was the case for security based automations like locks and garage door openers. It’s disappointing. But I’m open to workarounds……

Comment: @samh Yeah, that's annoying, I was looking to connect to a specific WiFi network when I enable Airplane mode, but that wasn't working so... Also, not sure there might be a workaround for that, it's location-based and I doubt there might be something. But maybe someone will come with something (not sure though).